# Bold the Title name for a powerbi Visual

Tags: powerbi

Is there a way to make the Title bold. I want to use **Lucida Sans font**. But there is no option to make the Lucida Sans font Bold in power bi.

I donot want to use other bold fonts provided by powerbi

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any option to make header bolder or italic etc. Power BI allows us to choose only the font. But you may try downloading "Lucida Sans Bold font" and moving it in Font Folder, which you can find in Control Panel